# html element appear twice in .net core angular project template

Tags: asp.net, angular, .net-core

I'm working on a visual studio 2017 template project of .net core 2 + Angular SPA template.

I'm having a problem that some of html elements appear twice, 1 appearance with css applied and the other isn't.
when i deploy the app it looks like in the image below.
As you can see the place holder 'Choose a number' and the dropdown arrow appear twice.

When i press the upper arrow 2 dropdowns are opened with the options.
If i press the downer arrow only the downer dropdown opened.
the whole div should be coloured in blue but only the "not in place" elements are blue.

the component is a prime-NG component but it occurs with other NPM packages (kendo UI for example).

I assume that it might be related to the order of css files and NPM loading during bootstrap but I can't find the place

index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<app>Loading...</app>

<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>@ViewData["Title"] - GSM.WebMonitorTool</title>
        <base href="~/" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()

        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

choose-number.component.html:

```
<div class="query-context-all">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <p-dropdown [options]="numbers" [(ngModel)]="chosenNumber" placeholder="Choose a number"></p-dropdown>
    </div>
</div>
```

choose-number.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
    selector: 'context-input',
    templateUrl: './context-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./context-input.component.css']
})

export class ContextInputComponent {

    chosenNumber: string;

    numbers: SelectItem[];

    constructor() {
        this.numbers = [
            { label: "1", value: "1" }, 
            { label: "2", value: "2" },
            { label: "3", value: "3" }];
    }
}
```

[image: component with 2 placeholders and 2 dropdowns]

Comment: have `Layout = null`  set within the **templates**  so the Layout doesn't get `rendered again`.

Comment: did you forget to add the css files for **prime-NG** in `webpack.config`?

Comment: @KarthikeyanNagaraj I'm not sure i understood what you mean by saying templates. Where should i add this line?

Comment: @JohnVelasquez thanks!! that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to John Velasquez, I understood that i had to add primeNG's css file to webpack. Actually each shared components or fonts npm may require this addition. As a beginner with Angular i didn't know they must be added explicitly so I add here my steps that solved it, hoping it will save some time for others :)
steps:

- adding the css file to webpack.config.vendor.vs - add the line `'primeng/resources/primeng.css'` to `nonTreeShakableModules` array
- update the rules of shared config, a few lines down, to `{ test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|jpe?g|gif)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }`
- run `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`
  from cmd/powershell, when path is the project folder.